# 'Invalid object name' error in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting `Invalid object name Clients` error in my SSRS reports.
I have 2 reports connected to separate db. Both the db are same, first one works but not another one.

#### Error is:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>       Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet3'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>       Invalid object name 'Clients'.

Comment: Somewhere along the way you have made a mistake - but no one can really tell you where it is from the information you have provided. You have to debug the situation, starting the verifying that the datasource does indeed point to the correct database, and that your report has permissions to access it. And then check that the query is in fact referencing real tables from the connected database...

Comment: Does the query for `DataSet3` run in SSMS?

Comment: solved! stupid mistake, I was not able to connect to db properly. added correct connection string and solved the issue.